# when I try to use javaConfig with spring-Hibernate3 ,I can't get session.but just an exception

Tags: hibernate, spring-transactions, spring-java-config

i'm learning the  javaconfig recently.So i was trying to transport my xml config into javaConfig ,but after i finish my code while the project running on the tomcat,i got error when i try to get the session to query infor from my db.I was really confuseed.

After i read some blog,and search the possible reason on Internet,i got a possible explanation that the transaction seems not working properly.
(but the error shows the transaction works well.so I got no idea about it)

if I got the right assumption how could i correct the code?,if not,what's the reason for my issue?

Any advice could be help.

(sorry for my poor english ,i hope it won't bother you much.)

---

here is my java config code.

this class is writen for RootApplicationContext

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.*" })
@PropertySources({ @PropertySource(value = "classpath:database.properties"),
        @PropertySource(value = "classpath:hibernate.properties") })
@Import(value = { HibernateConfig.class, DruidConfig.class, TransactionConfig.class })
public class SpringContextConfig {

}
```

this is transaction javaConfig

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class TransactionConfig implements TransactionManagementConfigurer {

    @Resource
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    @Resource
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setDataSource(dataSource);
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        return txManager;
    }

    @Override
    public PlatformTransactionManager annotationDrivenTransactionManager() {
        return hibernateTransactionManager();
    }

}
```

this is the service need to be manage,I have put an @Transactionl on the Class

```
@Service("locationService")
@Transactional(value="transactionManager")
public class LocationServiceImpl implements LocationService {
    @Resource
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;      
    @Resource(name = "locationDaoImp")
    LocationDao dao;

    @Override
    public Location queryLocationById(String locationId) {
        return dao.queryLocationById(locationId);
    }
```

after i get the error,i have try to debug at the daoClass(as blow),but i always get an error when i use the method getCurrentSession()

```
Location location = (Location) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Location.class, locationId);
```

and this is the exception

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/orm/ObjectRetrievalFailureException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:539)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:420)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:257)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.queryLocationById(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.controller.LocationController$1.execute(LocationController.java:83)
    at com.test.service.ExecuteTaskService$1.run(ExecuteTaskService.java:22)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
```

Answer (score 0):

ok,after I try to add the spring-orm.jar to my project,everything seems to be ok,no more error,I can get the right answer,and the transaction is also working properly when i debug the program.

But i'm still confused about my operation,because my program works well without spring-orm with the xml config.(i'm sure about that it's no any difference between my javaConfig class with my xml config file.Because i just simply transported my xml file to javaConfig.)

welcome any comment below the question.